# How can one make a webpage where text is not highlightable?

Tags: javascript, html

Example: http://www.snopes.com/business/genius/genius.asp

None of the text is highlightable - I've never seen something like this.  Tried to look at the source code, but could not find, not did Google provide any answers.

I'm assuming it's a JS trick?  The text is in the source code, so it's not an image.  Actually nothing is highlightable on the page.

How is this done?

Comment: You know that JS can just be disabled? Anything that is security related or restricts the user's actions will eventually fail when implemented in JavaScript. Besides that: Don't change the default behaviour.

Comment: Please. NEVER. Do this. It's the webpage equivalent of an asshole

Comment: why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Not going to do it myself, was just curious how they did.  I've seen pages that autoinject "for more info visit" crap for SEO, but never where you cant copy at all.

Answer (score 9):

Read the source code of the page you have linked to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var omitformtags=["input", "textarea", "select"]
omitformtags=omitformtags.join("|")
function disableselect(e){
if (omitformtags.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase())==-1)
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
if (typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined")
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
else{
document.onmousedown=disableselect
document.onmouseup=reEnable
}
-->
</script>
```

In Chrome, entering `document.onselectstart = function() {return false}` into the Javascript console seems to do the trick.

But don't do it, it's infuriating.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not going to do it, was just puzzled when I saw it, since I have *never* seen something like this.

Comment: You've probably never seen it before because most web page authors have more sense than to think it adds value and realise it's just an annoyance that is easily worked around.

Comment: Right, which is guess is surprising that Snopes, which seems at least somewhat reputable, it's PR8 and averages 5M uniques, would do something like this.

Comment: I presume the value of this is protection against content scraping, I'm assuming?  I don't see any other reason why they would do this.

Answer (score 2):

This is the script area where they disable the selection:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var omitformtags=["input", "textarea", "select"]
omitformtags=omitformtags.join("|")
function disableselect(e){
if (omitformtags.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase())==-1)
return false
}
function reEnable(){
return true
}
if (typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined")
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false")
else{
document.onmousedown=disableselect
document.onmouseup=reEnable
}
-->
</script>
```

The document.onmousedown = disableselect is the key line.

Comment: Note the HTML comment delimiters inside script tags (and not even implemented correctly at that). A sure sign of a crappy script - if the senseless use of the Function constructor and an array to create a string aren't enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are also ways that don't require JS,

[-moz-user-select](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-user-select) (or -khtml-user-select for safari/chrome)

For IE/opera the [unselectable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-attribute

Answer (score 0):

It's this part of the page source:

```
function disableselect(e){
    if (omitformtags.indexOf(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase())==-1)
        return false
}

function reEnable(){
    return true
}

if (typeof document.onselectstart != "undefined")
    document.onselectstart = new Function ("return false");
else{
    document.onmousedown = disableselect;
    document.onmouseup = reEnable;
}
```